# How do I configure elasticsearch to retain documents up to 30 days?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a default data retention period in elasticsearch? If yes can you help me find the configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah you can set a TTL on the data. Take a look here for the configuration options available.

<s>http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html</s>

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/mapping-ttl-field.html

NB: This is now old functionality and replaced with index lifecycle management (ILM) as of ES version 2.0.0-beta2, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html

Comment: I'm relatively new to Elasticsearch, but keep in mind that if you're using Elasticsearch with Logstash (or similar), it will probably create a new index for each day's worth of data.  This means that you either have to manually update each index's `_ttl` property (yuck), or use an "Index Template" so that all given indexes are created with the `_ttl` property set.  Can anyone else confirm this approach?

Comment: The link 404's.

Comment: This link is no longer working. @goalie7960 might need to update it.

Comment: @Underoos Anyone can...

Answer (score 10):

This is no longer supported in Elasticsearch 5.0.0 or greater. The best practice is to create indexes periodically (daily is most common) and then delete the index when the data gets old enough.

Here's a reference to how to delete an index (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html)

This article (though it's old enough to reference _ttl) also gives some insight: https://www.elastic.co/blog/using-elasticsearch-and-logstash-to-serve-billions-of-searchable-events-for-customers

As a reminder, it's best to protect your Elasticsearch cluster from the outside world via a proxy and restrict the methods that can be sent to your cluster. This way you can prevent your cluster from being ransomed.

Comment: What exactly is no longer supported in Elasticsearch 5 or greater?

Answer (score 4):

Elasticsearch curator is the tool to use if you want to manage your indexes: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html

Here's an example of how to delete indices based on age: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/ex_delete_indices.html

Combine with cron to have this done at regular intervals.

Answer (score 2):

There is no default retention period but new versions of Elasticsearch have [index lifecycle management (ILM)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html). It allows to:

> Delete stale indices to enforce data retention standards

[Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/set-up-lifecycle-policy.html).

Simple policy example:

```
PUT _ilm/policy/my_policy
{
    "policy": {
        "phases": {
            "delete": {
                "min_age": "30d",
                "actions": {
                    "delete": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you use OpenSearch in AWS then take a look at [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/ism.html) for the same thing.

Pretty old question but I got the same question just now. Maybe it will be helpful for somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI if you are using AWS's Elasticsearch service, they have a great doc on [Using Curator to Rotate Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/curator.html) which includes some sample python code that can be used in a Lambda function.